# How IntelliJ (or sbt-structure) identifies test sources?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

**Background**

I've created [template-scala-project](http://github.com/frgomes/template-scala-project) which, among other amenities, defines configurations `FunctionalTest` and `AcceptanceTest` (in addition to `IntegrationTest`, which is provided by SBT).

This way, the relevant bits of the directory structure are:

```
src/main/scala - compile sources - Compile
src/test/scala - test sources - Test
src/it/scala - it sources - IntegrationTest
src/ft/scala - ft sources - FunctionalTest
src/at/scala - at sources - AcceptanceTest
```

**Behavior in SBT**

I can run only functional tests, for example, like this:

> ft:test

Everything works as I've planned. I can even share *test sources* to *it sources*, or *ft sources*, or *at sources*... which is a common practical requirement.

**Behaviour in IntelliJ**

IntelliJ recognizes that `src/test/scala` and `src/it/scala` are test sources. IntelliJ does not have any distinction between them, I mean: no distinction between test sources and integration test sources, ... but it's OK. All I need is that `src/it/scala` is recognized as test sources. And it works as that.

However, IntelliJ does not recognize `src/ft/scala` as test sources; IntelliJ does not recognize `src/at/scala` as test sources.

I have inspected the XML file produced by sbt-structure but I was unable to understand the pattern or logic behind it. However (and apparently!) `src/ft/scala` and `src/at/scala` should appear under `<configuration id="test">` in order to be eligible for being considered as test sources.

**Question**

In order to test my hypothesis above, I would like to force `src/ft/scala` to appear under `<configuration id="test">`, employing "something" in the `build.sbt` file. How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.

Comment: @y.bedrov: Apparently I found a way to "make it work". The details are in my answer. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I apparently found something which works well enough. I cannot claim that I've found a solution, but at least it seems to work as I would expect: IntelliJ recognizes `FunctionalTest` (test) sources and `AcceptanceTest` (test) sources, the same way it recognizes `Test` sources and `IntegrationTest` sources.

Answer:

Create a configuration which extends `Runtime` and `Test`. Doing this way, `src/ft/scala` appears under `<configuration id="test">`, as the XML file is produced by `sbt-structure`. See the example below for configuration `FunctionalTest`:

```
lazy val FunctionalTest = Configuration.of("FunctionalTest", "ft") extend (Runtime, Test)
```

As a bonus, I show below some other settings which I find useful to be associated to configuration `FunctionalTest`:

```
lazy val forkSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  Seq(
    fork in ThisScope := false,
    parallelExecution in ThisScope := false,
  )

lazy val ftSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  inConfig(FunctionalTest)(Defaults.testSettings ++ forkSettings ++
    Seq(
      unmanagedSourceDirectories   in FunctionalTest ++= (sourceDirectories   in Test).value,
      unmanagedResourceDirectories in FunctionalTest ++= (resourceDirectories in Test).value,
    ))
```

I also did something similar for configuration `AcceptanceTest`.

You can find a project which exercises such kind of configurations at:
http://github.com/frgomes/template-scala-project

Answer (score 0):

If you want a directory in IntelliJ to be considered a Test Source directory, you can configure it as such by simply right clicking it and selecting `Mark Directory As > Test Sources Root`

That changes your project structure configuration to let IntelliJ know that tests reside there.  The same is true of your resources if those need to be marked appropriately.

With THAT said, I suppose I'm not 100% sure if IntelliJ's use of sbt will recognize that and run them appropriately, but I would expect it to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your friendly message. I'm aware of the instructions you mentioned. However, I would like obtain just the right thing without having to force anything in IntelliJ. If SBT knows it and if IntelliJ integrates with SBT, then IntelliJ should understand SBT properly. And no... unfortunately IntelliJ will "forget" these sort of manual settings everytime you reopen your project or refresh your build.sbt.